# How to make all text lines the same height or distance

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, affinity-publisher

I have a problem that actually annoyed me for quite a while in text editing software, only now I have a case where it's hard to ignore it:

###### Maybe it's some simple general feature but I never knew how to fix this:

The problem is that
**the distance** of `lines of text that switched to the new line automatically` is different from when you `switch to the next line manually` (by pressing enter).

This can be nice, of course, if wanted, but when you simply want to scale the distances of a whole text field, and the auto-switched lines become unreadably overlapping, that's pretty annoying and more. It's like they're multiplied instead of overwritten or sth?!
If somebody knew **how to change this** behaviour in other Software like Word or InDesign, this may help as well, maybe that would help finding the feature **in Affinity Publisher** (v1) as well.

I'd like them to scale the same.

Comment: Maybe just changing the line height will be the best fix for this, but I can't even find that 'setting' in Af-Publisher

Answer (score 1):

No comment about Adobe software, but in Affinity Publisher you start a new paragraph by pressing the Enter key.  Paragraph style definitions have such items as space above and below the paragraph. Make them zero and the line distance difference problem vanishes.

Both Paragraph and Character styles have such item as Leading (name is taken from over 500 year old metal type vocabulary) which means how much space is inserted between the lines. Character style leading overrides the paragraph style leading. Better to learn carefully how the style concepts work. Otherwise it's slow to create regular looking text layouts and you feel you are fighting against the program.